# Cumulative count for calculating daily frequency using SQL query (in Amazon Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, cumulative-frequency

I have a dataset contains 'UI' (unique id), time, frequency (frequency for give value in UI column), as it is shown here:

[image]

What I would like to add a new column named 'daily_frequency' which simply counts each unique value in UI column for a given day sequentially as I show in the image below.

[image]

For example if UI=114737 and it is repeated 2 times in one day, we should have 1, and 2 in the daily_frequency column.

I could do that with Python and Panda package using group by and cumcount methods as follows ...

```
df['daily_frequency'] = df.groupby(['UI','day']).cumcount()+1
```

However, for some reason, **I must do this via SQL queries (Amazon Redshift)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a running count, which could be calculated as:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ui, TRUNC(time) ORDER BY time
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS daily_frequency
```

Comment: Thanks Salman for quick reply. I have tried what you suggested, however, I got the following error message `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;` ...

Comment: @AminKiany . . . That is something of a peculiarity of Redshift.

Comment: @SalmanA: Thanks Salman for the answer.  I also edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Although Salman's answer seems to be correct, I think `ROW_NUMBER()` is simpler:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ui, time::date
               ORDER BY time
              ) AS daily_frequency
```